# How to merge two cells of a qtable row?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a table using qtablewidget. I would like to selectively merge cells of some rows. Is there any built-in function for that(sorry, I couldn't find one)?  Otherwise, please specify how it can be done. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the [setSpan](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtableview.html#setSpan) function of [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtableview.html) (which QTableWidget inherits) to achieve something like that for rows and columns.

That is, unless you're looking to really just merge individual cells. I'm not sure that can be achieved with setSpan, but have a look at it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try [QTableWidget::setSpan(int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan);](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan)

But in some versions it [doesn't work](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-255).

Answer (score -2):

Sample program

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QHeaderView>


class TestWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QTableWidget *testTable;
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
    QPushButton *button;
public:
    TestWidget(QWidget *parent=nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        testTable = new QTableWidget;

        testTable = new QTableWidget(this);
        testTable->setObjectName("testTable");
        testTable->setFixedWidth(400);
        testTable->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Minimum);
        testTable->setColumnCount(4);
        testTable->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        testTable->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

        QTableWidgetItem *itemC1 = new QTableWidgetItem("Column 1");
        testTable->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, itemC1);
        QTableWidgetItem *itemC2 = new QTableWidgetItem("Column 2");
        testTable->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, itemC2);
        QTableWidgetItem *itemC3 = new QTableWidgetItem("Column 3");
        testTable->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, itemC3);
        QTableWidgetItem *itemC4 = new QTableWidgetItem("Column 4");
        testTable->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, itemC4);
        testTable->setColumnWidth(0,100);
        testTable->setColumnWidth(1,100);
        testTable->setColumnWidth(2,100);
        testTable->setColumnWidth(3,100);
        testTable->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
        testTable->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked | QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed);
        testTable->setProperty("showDropIndicator", QVariant(false));
        testTable->setDragDropOverwriteMode(false);
        testTable->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
        testTable->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
        testTable->setShowGrid(true);
        testTable->setGridStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
        testTable->setSortingEnabled(false);
        testTable->setCornerButtonEnabled(false);
        testTable->horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections(false);
        testTable->horizontalHeader()->setProperty("showSortIndicator", QVariant(false));
        testTable->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
        testTable->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

        button = new QPushButton("Group");
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(buttonClicked(bool)));
        mainLayout->addWidget(testTable);
        mainLayout->addWidget(button);
        this->setLayout(mainLayout);
    }

    void addRow(QString c1, QString c2, QString c3, QString c4)
    {
        int row = testTable->rowCount();
        testTable->insertRow(row);

        QTableWidgetItem *c1Item = new QTableWidgetItem(c1);
        QTableWidgetItem *c2Item = new QTableWidgetItem(c2);
        QTableWidgetItem *c3Item = new QTableWidgetItem(c3);
        QTableWidgetItem *c4Item = new QTableWidgetItem(c4);
        c1Item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
        c2Item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
        c3Item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
        c4Item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
        testTable->setItem(row, 0, c1Item);
        testTable->setItem(row, 1, c2Item);
        testTable->setItem(row, 2, c3Item);
        testTable->setItem(row, 3, c4Item);
    }

    void updateCell(int rowNumber, int columnNumber, QString textString)
    {
        if(rowNumber>=testTable->rowCount() || columnNumber>=testTable->columnCount()) return;
        testTable->item(rowNumber, columnNumber)->setText(textString);
    }

    void groupCells(int rowNumber, int columnNumber, int rowSpan, int columnSpan)
    {
        if(rowNumber>=testTable->rowCount() || columnNumber>=testTable->columnCount()) return;
        testTable->setSpan(rowNumber,columnNumber,rowSpan,columnSpan);
    }

    void ungroupCells(int rowNumber, int columnNumber)
    {
        if(rowNumber>=testTable->rowCount() || columnNumber>=testTable->columnCount()) return;
        testTable->setSpan(rowNumber,columnNumber,1,1);
    }

public slots:
    void buttonClicked(bool event)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event)
        if(button->text()=="Group")
        {
            groupCells(1,1,2,1);
            button->setText("Ungroup");
        }
        else
        {
            ungroupCells(1,1);
            button->setText("Group");
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TestWidget wid;
    wid.addRow("0,0", "0,1", "0,2", "0,3");
    wid.addRow("1,0", "1,1", "1,2", "1,3");
    wid.addRow("2,0", "2,1", "2,2", "2,3");
    wid.addRow("3,0", "3,1", "3,2", "3,3");
    wid.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Project file shall be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/VinuRajaKumar/stackoverflow/tree/main/TableWidgetCellGrouping)