# Is there a way to add additional column in row header of QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

Here is my requirement:

I am using Qt 4.8. I need to group a number of rows in a QTableWidget. I have 2 ways of doing it:

1. Color the table items for those many rows/coulmns. I may have performance issues due to coloring.
2. Grouping the rows by adding an additional column in the row header, and entering the group header text so that the group can be identified.

Can anyone help with the second option please.

Note: I do not want to use QicsTable.

Comment: It will improve readability to display 1 and 2 as a list.

Comment: Regarding 2. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504782/how-to-merge-two-cells-of-a-qtable-row

Comment: Thanks. Is there a similar solution for the headers? can we have sub section in a header or split the vertical header?