# Multiple-row tableview in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, tableview

Couldn't find any help on this but I know it can be done. Trying to achieve this:

[image: multi-row table]

Basically combining 2 columns into 1. Not sure exactly how to describe it.

Not sure where to start, maybe a rule based (eg row is even) tableview class?
Couldn't find anything similar in the documentation either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear, especially since you're talking about "combining 2 columns", but I don't see any of that in the image. Besides, it just seems that what's happening there is that two rows are fundamentally selected at the same time, but they are still distinct rows.

Comment: I suspect you may want to use [setSpan()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6505023/9705687). That original question was for C++,  but it applies to Python just as well.